# Prevent simultaneous requests from single user in django-rest-framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

Users cause race condition on critical data processing by clicking button twice accidentally and by spamming web server to gain more points. I'm thinking about using some kind of per user lock at the beginning of request processing to prevent both data corruption and server overloading. The problem is that the request processing is distributed between machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a violation of the RESTful concept that there is [no session state](https://restfulapi.net/statelessness/) maintained between REST API calls on the server; all state is maintained by the client. Perhaps you can make your code [idempotent](https://restfulapi.net/idempotent-rest-apis/) so that multiple submissions will just PUT the value based on what was last retrieved via GET. I assume the resource your user is updating is identified as theirs (e.g. an attribute of the given user). You could also consider POSTing something to a queue with a 202 Accepted response and then the queue is drained by another process that implements whatever policy you like. This would require the client to poll with another GET to learn the result.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably set a throttle to only allow for a request every x seconds that way users won't be able to spam the button, I have not used it my self but based on the docs it may be what you need.

source:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#throttling

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a one-time token that expires immediately after the request. It also means that every time you request a new token and use it during the API call.